# Automatically detect and read qr code with usb webcam in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a QR Code reader with USB webcam.

I can read the QR Code press the Capture button. I need to do that automatically when detect the QR Code.

I need to create my application like this.
[Android Studio Tutorial - Scan QR Code by Camera](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o69UqAKi47I)

This is my Code

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WebCam_Capture;
using MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec;
using MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.Data;

namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private WebCamCapture _myWebcam;

        private WebCamCapture MyWebcam
        {
            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
            get
            {
                return _myWebcam;
            }

            [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
            set
            {
                if (_myWebcam != null)
                {
                    _myWebcam.ImageCaptured -= MyWebcam_ImageCaptured;
                }

                _myWebcam = value;
                if (_myWebcam != null)
                {
                    _myWebcam.ImageCaptured += MyWebcam_ImageCaptured;
                }
            }
        }

        private QRCodeDecoder _reader;

        private void MyWebcam_ImageCaptured(object source, WebcamEventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox1.Image = e.WebCamImage;
        }

        private void StartWebcam()
        {
            try
            {
                StopWebcam();
                MyWebcam = new WebCamCapture();
                MyWebcam.Start(0);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

        private void StopWebcam()
        {
            try
            {
                MyWebcam.Stop();
                MyWebcam.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

        private void Capture()
        {
            try
            {
                _reader = new QRCodeDecoder();
                TextBox1.Text = _reader.Decode(new QRCodeBitmapImage(PictureBox1.Image as Bitmap));
                MessageBox.Show(@"QR code is detected!");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartWebcam();
            TextBox1.Clear();
        }

        private void btn_capture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Capture();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any specific problem you are facing?

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Yes i can detect automatically qr code and read it

Comment: your question is too broad and unclear. So just to understand you need your system to make action when it detect QR code automatically. if so That requires the camera running all the time, is that the idea? you need to be specific and clear with you communication.

Comment: Yes.that is right. i'm sorry my english is poor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Unity](https://unity3d.com/), they have a free version for beginners and support C#.
For the QR code/webcam part, you can [make a search](https://assetstore.unity.com/search/?k=qr%20code%20reader&order_by=relevance&q=qr&q=code&q=reader&rows=42) on their Asset Store or on [Github](https://github.com/search?q=qr%20code%20unity).